# Get PyCharm to stop asking for a VCS?

Tags: pycharm

How do I get PyCharm to stop asking for Git integration, or any other VCS?
(my version is 4.0.4 professional)

It keeps popping up telling me it couldn't find git.exe, but I wouldn't want it to integrate anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the Git plugin in Settings | Plugins.

Answer (score 1):

(Note:  I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, but the interfaces and menus are similar.)

Under Project Settings, navigate to the Version Control submenu. From there, select "none" as your VCS.

[image]

It could be the case that you have a .git folder somewhere in that project too.  If you really don't want it, consider renaming it to something like .git-unused or something along those lines.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm not sure I understood your comment at the end, I do have a .git folder because it is a git project, only I don't want pycharm to handle it for me (I'm using another app).

Comment: This only disables version control for the current project. The other disables it for any project ever.